# IE 11 : divs positioning with zoom greater than one - Works well in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a very simple question. ***How do I make the divs position to work in IE when zoom is greater than one (ex: zoom: 1.467)***?

I have created a simple jsFiddle. if you view the result full screen in Chrome, divs are positioned as expected. But id you see the same result in IE11, divs are randomly positioned. Please note, when zoom set to 1, it works absolutely fine in IE too.

I believe this is pure css issue with IE.

How can I make it working in IE same as Chrome?

***jsFiddle Full Screen Result:*** https://jsfiddle.net/vinayak_nandi/fd6ch7yh/5/embedded/result/

***jsFiddle for editing:*** https://jsfiddle.net/vinayak_nandi/fd6ch7yh/5/

I really appreciate the help.

Thanks in advance

**Images:**

**1. When viewed the result on Chrome** (each div with zoom:1.4671..):

[image]

**2. When veiwed the result in IE 11 (each div with zoom:1.4671..):**

[image]

**HTML and CSS Snippets**

```
<div id="app">
   <div class="widget" id="img1">image div 1</div>
   <div class="widget" id="img2">image div 2</div>
   <div class="widget" id="img3">image div 3</div>
   <div class="widget" id="img4">image div 4</div>
   <div class="widget" id="img5">image div 5</div>
   <div class="widget" id="img6">image div 6</div>
   <div class="widget" id="img7">image div 7</div>
   <div class="widget" id="img8">image div 8</div>
</div>

-- ** -- Styles -- ** --
    #app{
        height: 1000px; 
        width: 1920px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    .widget {
      -moz-border-radius: 3px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      background-color: #C0C0C0;
      -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
      background-clip: padding-box;
      -moz-background-clip: padding-box;
      display: inline-block;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      border: solid 1px rgb(75, 75, 75);
      position: absolute;
      zoom: 1.467125382263;
    }
    #img1{
        left: 541px; 
        top: 6px; 
        width: 220px; 
        height: 237px; 
    }
    #img2{ 
      left: 14px;
      top: 249px;
      width: 309px;
      height: 438px;
    }
    #img3{
      left: 15px;
      top: 7px;
      width: 222px;
      height: 237px;
    }
    #img4{
      left: 242px;
      top: 7px;
      width: 294px;
      height: 237px;
    }
    #img5{
      left: 766px;
      top: 6px;
      width: 284px;
      height: 237px;
    }
    #img6{
      left: 1056px;
      top: 6px;
      width: 251px;
      height: 237px;
    }
    #img7{
      left: 829px;
      top: 249px;
      width: 477px;
      height: 438px;
    }
    #img8{
      left: 329px;
      top: 249px;
      width: 496px;
      height: 438px;
    }
```

Comment: you do know that zoom doesn't work with every browser right?

Comment: @loli do you have a link to for this? http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom says ie's from 9 should support zoom without prefix. however I'm facing a problem when zoom not working and can't find any related info

Answer (score 0):

Try using percentages instead of fixed pixel widths - this will make your layout fluid.

e.g. Instead of having this CSS:

```
#img1{
    left: 541px; 
    top: 6px; 
    width: 220px; 
    height: 237px; 
}
```

try this:

```
   #img1{
    left: 20%; 
    top: 2%; 
    width: 10%; 
    height: 11%; 
}
```

This will make your layout respond to the size of the users screen.

Note: these are only example percentage sizes you will have to play around with the values to get your desired result.